# Pycharm resolves modules twice (deployed and local code)

Tags: pycharm

I'm using pycharm with a remote Interpreter.

The code from my Project I'm working on is already installed/deployed in the remote server's
PYTHONPATH (it was already when I started to create the pycharm project and configured the remote interpreter).

Now the problem is that Pycharm seems to "resolve" modules/packages twice:

- from the local project source
- from the "python_stubs" generated from the remote interpreter

This in fact causes, that autocompletion does no longer work correctly.

[image: screenshot]

Is it possible to exclude specific packages from the "python_stubs" that are generated, to work around this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting `Python Interpreters` or `Project Structure` in PyCharm preferences.

[image]

[image]

If you see redundant code paths or modules, then you want to remove them so that there is only one reference to each code path in the set.

Comment: Hmm ... in "Project Interpreter" -> "Paths" I have only a single entry , which is "/home/powo/pycharm-3.0.1/helpers/python-skeletons" in my case. IMHO this is automatically populated for remote interpreters and  I cannot find any option to exclude specific directories/packages there.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the PyCharm cache folder will resolve the problem. Seems that there is a bug related to cache in PyCharm.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-45326 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44801